# Is correct this pattern for an asynchronous TCP listener?

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, tcplistener

I was wondering if I'm doing right in an application I'm building. The app has to receive incoming TCP connections, and use a thread per call, so the server can answer multiple calls in parallel.

What I'm doing is call `BeginAcceptTcpClient` again as soon I got an accepted client. I guess that when the `ConnectionAccepted` method is hit, it's actually in a separate thread.

```
public class ServerExample:IDisposable
{
    TcpListener _listener;
    public ServerExample()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10034);
        _listener.Start();
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionAccepted,null);
    }

    private void ConnectionAccepted(IAsyncResult ia)
    {
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionAccepted, null);
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ia);

            // work with your client
            // when this method ends, the poolthread is returned
            // to the pool.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle or rethrow the exception
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Am I doing right?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could make the method static like this :

```
private static void ConnectionAccepted(IAsyncResult ia)
    {         
     var listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
     TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient();
     listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionAccepted, listener);
     // .....
     }
```

maybe you don't want it to be static but this way you could move the method where you like it and do not depend on member variables in this class but another one.
I.E: decouple server tcp logic and server client logic.

Comment: `EndAcceptTcpClient()` could throw an exception and result in `BeginAcceptTcpClient` never being called and thus killing the "server".

I personally came here looking for answer on if it is ok to call  `BeginAcceptTcpClient` before `EndAcceptTcpClient()` in the callback